# Geometric distribution of independent t random variables and their limit

Tags: probability

let there be $X_1,X_2,...,X_t$ independent random variables that are distributed $X_i\text{~}Geo(\frac{1}{2})$ for every $1\le i \le t$. Show that there is a constant $c \gt 0 $ so that for every $a \gt 3$ and every $t \ge 1$:

$$ P(X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_t \ge a \cdot t) \le 2^{-c \cdot a \cdot t}$$

Mention specifically the constant and prove its correctness.

So far I tried using Chernoff bounds but I am not able to complete the calculation due to the $\delta$, the expected value can be found due to the geometry of the the random variable, moreover is that they are independent so we can also find variance but I don't see a use for it at the moment.
I have also tried maybe getting the expression to the central limit theorem but that was a dead end as well, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes you are right, i edited.

Answer (score 1):

$E[e^{sX_1}]=\sum_k (1/2)^{k+1}e^{sk}=1/(2-e^s). $ Therefore, the mgf for $X_1+\dots+X_t$ is $(2-e^{s})^{-t}$, valid for all $s<\ln 2$.

For any $0<s<\ln 2$,
$$
P(X_1+\dots+X_t\ge at)=P(e^{s(X_1+\dots+X_t)}\ge e^{sat})\le\frac{E[e^{s(X_1+\dots+X_t)}]}{e^{sat}}= e^{-sat}(2-e^s)^{-t}.
$$
Now choose $s$ so that $2-e^s=e^{-1/2}$, namely $s=\log(2-e^{-1/2})\approx 0.33$. Then since $sa \ge 0.33\cdot 3\ge 3/4$, we have $\frac23 sa\ge \frac12$, so
$$
P(X_1+\dots+X_t\ge at)\le e^{-sat}\cdot e^{t/2}=e^{-(sa-\frac12)t}\ge e^{-(sa-\frac23sa)t}=2^{-(\log_2 e)sat/3}.$$